# How can I use user profile-name after sub path in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink

my actual link is [www.example.com/blogs.php?username=james](http://www.example.com/blogs.php?username=james)
and I want to short this as [www.exapmle.com/blogs/james](http://www.exapmle.com/blogs/james)

I've tried this but it is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blogs.php?username=$1 [L]
```

can anyone please help me out here?

complete .htaccess file is this...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

     RewriteRule ^(register)$ register.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(blogPage)$ blogPage.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(new-feed)$ new-feed.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(all-feeds)$ all-feeds.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(read-lists)$ read-lists.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(bookmarks)$ bookmarks.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(history)$ history.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^(drafts)$ drafts.php [L]
     RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blogs.php?profile_username=$1 [L] 
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
     RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_username=$1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blogs.php?username=$1 [L]` (only have the parentheses around what you want to catch)

Comment: I've updated the question. It is still not working properly. Page is opening but it is weird, looks like without CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much. it is working now after resolving the CSS path issue.